# Create Search with recordType and columns with 'and' && 'or' doesn't work

Tags: search, filter, types, transactions, netsuite

when I am run this code I get some Invoice / credit mémo  / payment ... (all transactions type possible)

If I remove the filters, it work and I get only sales order , I tried to add the record.Type.SALES_ORDER in filters , it doesn't work too.

```
        var searchToload = search.load(searchid)
        var myColumns = searchToload.columns
        var dateDelaysPrebook = moment(moment().subtract(4, 'months'), 'MM/DD/YYYY').format('MM/DD/YYYY')
        var dateDelaysNotPrebook = moment(moment().subtract(1, 'days'), 'MM/DD/YYYY').format('MM/DD/YYYY')

        // create list of filters 
        var f1Dyn = ['subsidiary', search.Operator.IS, sub]
        var f1prebook = ['custbody_ndk_us_order_types', search.Operator.ANYOF, [1, 7, 8, 13]]
        var f2prebook = ['datecreated', search.Operator.ONORAFTER, dateDelaysPrebook]
        var f1others = ['custbody_ndk_us_order_types', search.Operator.NONEOF, [1, 7, 8, 13]]
        var f2others = ['datecreated', search.Operator.ONORAFTER, dateDelaysNotPrebook]
        var f2others = ['datecreated', search.Operator.ONORAFTER, dateDelaysNotPrebook]

        var filterarr = [f1Dyn,'and', [f1prebook, 'and',f2prebook], 'or', [f1others, 'and',f2others]]
        var mysearch = search.create({type: search.Type.SALES_ORDER, filters: filterarr, columns: mycolumn})
        return mysearch
```

Comment: One option is to create a saved search in the UI then use a browser plugin to see it as code.

Answer (score 0):

```
var filterarr = ["type","anyof","CustCred","CustInvc","SalesOrd"];

var mysearch = search.create({   type: "transaction", 
 filters: filterarr, columns: mycolumn})
```

SS 2.0

Answer (score 0):

You can see the available fields [here](https://www.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/srbrowser/Browser2020_1/script/record/transaction.html), and the one that you want to use is

```
[ 'recordtype', 'is', record.Type.SALES_ORDER ]
```